# Invalid Host header when running Create React App on localhost subdomain

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

After updating to  the react-scripts 1.0.0 I get this error when I try to open my app in the browser on a localhost subdomain: 'Invalid Host header'

My app was set up to serve different data for different subdomains:
group1.localhost:3000
group2.localhost:3000
...

I found that adding the code below to my webpack config should fix the problem.

```
devServer: {
  disableHostCheck: true
}
```

But how can i fix it in CRA without ejecting?

Comment: For multiple subdomains please track this issue: https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2233.

Comment: Even with the initial solution you had (```devServer: {
  disableHostCheck: true
}```) I still couldn't fix this problem. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please update to `react-scripts@1.0.2`.
It fixes this issue for users who don't use the `proxy` feature in React.

If you **do** use the `proxy` feature, please [follow these instructions](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy).

Comment: it says add `HOST=mypublicdevhost.com` where do I find / what is my "mypublicdevhost" ?

Comment: add it in the .env.development file at the root folder

Comment: just to mention that, as of today, that "instructions" link is not working anymore. Not sure   whether it should point to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#invalid-host-header-errors-after-configuring-proxy

Answer (score 21):

An easy solution for development environment would be to set the following environment variable: `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true`

That can be done by e.g. adding that line to `.env` file in the root of the project. Note that this is not a secure solution and should not be used in production.

Comment: How sketchy would it be to use this in a production env?

Comment: what should use in production ?

Comment: The question and this answer applies to `start` script which starts a development server. In production you should run `build` script to build a production bundle. This static bundle is then served to users using a web server, e.g. Nginx or Apache. It's also possible to use Node.JS for that, e.g. Express package.

Answer (score 4):

Solved it by adding `0.0.0.0 <domain>` in my `/etc/hosts` in addition to adding the domain to the `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks! This was my scenario as well. I had a `HOST=local.companydomain.com` in an `.env` as well, but needed to add `0.0.0.0 local.companydomain.com` in my `/etc/hosts`. [Reference to 0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

Add the HOST in your `.env` file, then create react app will your host, rather than `localhost`. If it doesn't fix the issue then add `DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK=true` in the `.env` file.

Don't forget to restart the development server.

```
HOST=mydevserver.com
```

Answer (score 0):

running a basic `yarn` command fixed things for me