# Server doesn't work with HOST variable in .env (Create React App)

Tags: environment-variables, localhost, create-react-app, dotenv

I use create-react-app and trying to set `HOST=custom.local` variable with `.env` file.
But it is always ignored with the message:

```
Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: custom.localhost
If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.
```

Also, I see this:

```sh
echo $HOST
M1-Air // <- my laptop name
```

So, how I understand this variable is already set and `dotenv` within CRA won't overwrite it and just ignores, but any suggestions on what I need to do to set my custom HOST variable for CRA anyway?

I've found a similar issue on GitHub but it doesn't have any suggestions on how to resolve it:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my issue isn't caused by reassigning the variable, but because my custom hostname `custom.localhost` isn't mapped to any IP, even there is no such message.

Solved it by adding `0.0.0.0 custom.localhost` in my `/etc/hosts` in addition to adding the domain to the `.env` file.

I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52595624/344306

Answer (score 0):

edit in .env or maybe .config file and replace the given host to localhost or HOST=127.0.0.1, it will solve this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).